# JSF DataTable will not display values

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

I have a `<p:dataTable>` in in an `xhtml` page. The table will not display the values for the backing bean. I have debugged to the point that I know that the getter for the bean is getting called, and I also know that there are items in this bean. Any ideas for why this is? Netbeans 7.3, JSF2.2, Tomcat 7, jdk1.7, primefaces 4.0.

Here is my table, this is inside of a form called 'mainForm'

```
<p:dataTable id="DTsamples" widgetVar="DTsamplesVw" var="sample" value="#{alterSampleController.samples}" 
                             filteredValue="#{alterSampleController.filteredSamples}" paginator="true" rows="20"
                             sortMode="multiple" scrollable="true" rowStyleClass="#{sample.rowColorByType}">

<p:column headerText="Lab Number" footerText="Lab Number" sortBy="labNumber" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="labNumber" filterMaxLength="20">  
                        #{sample.labNumber}                            
</p:column> 

<p:column headerText="Container ID" footerText="Container ID" sortBy="containerID" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="containerID" filterMaxLength="11">  
                        #{sample.containerID}                            
</p:column> 

<p:column headerText="Sample Type" footerText="Sample Type" sortBy="sampleType" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="sampleType" filterMaxLength="50">  
                        #{sample.sampleType}
</p:column> 

<p:column headerText="Field ID" footerText="Field ID" sortBy="fieldID" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="fieldID" filterMaxLength="150">  
                        #{sample.fieldID}
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Sample ID" footerText="Sample ID" sortBy="sampleID" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="sampleID" filterMaxLength="150">  
                        #{sample.sampleID}
</p:column>

<p:column headerText="Grower" footerText="Grower" sortBy="grower" filterMatchMode="contains" filterBy="grower" filterMaxLength="50">  
                        #{sample.grower}
</p:column>

~~~A few other columns that don't contain data~~~~

</p:dataTable>
```

Here is a dialog that gets the results from a search

```
<h:form id="innerSearch"><p:dialog id="searchDialogID" widgetVar="searchDialog" header="Sample search" resizable="false" draggable="false" showEffect="puff"
                      hideEffect="puff" appendToBody="false" modal="true" rendered="#{alterSampleController.allowReading eq true}">

~~~Bunch of inputTexts and selectoneMenus to get search details                

<p:commandButton update=":mainForm" process="innerSearch" icon="ui-icon-search" value="Search" actionListener="#{alterSampleController.loadSearch}" oncomplete="searchDialog.hide()"/>

</p:dialog>
</h:form>
```

Relevant Backing Bean

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped


public class AlterSampleController implements Serializable {    
private ArrayList<SampleAlter> _samples;
 private ArrayList<SampleAlter> _filteredSamples;

public void loadSearch() {
    UIComponent table = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":mainForm:DTsamples");
    table.setValueExpression("sortBy", null);
    if (_samples != null) {
        _samples.clear();
    }
    _samples = _saHelper.searchList(getSearch());


    }
    getAgronomers().clear();
    getGrowers().clear();
}
    public ArrayList<SampleAlter> getSamples() {
    return _samples;
}
    public ArrayList<SampleAlter> getFilteredSamples() {
    return _filteredSamples;
}


public void setFilteredSamples(ArrayList<SampleAlter> filteredSamples) {
    this._filteredSamples = filteredSamples;
}
}
```

Comment: Does the attribute alterSampleController.filteredSamples exist ?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar yes it does, I edited the code and shows it now.

Comment: Just a couple of suggestions: be sure you're not nesting forms (the id's indicate you are...). Try putting the form inside the dialog, I believe thats normally recommended. Try using appendToBody="true"

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar No nested forms, tried appendToBody="true" and switching the dialog and form around still nothing.

Comment: The normal would be to use process="@form" instead of process="innerSearch", but it'll probably make no difference. Sorry have run out of ideas

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar Thanks, but no dice.

Comment: Code is working fine for me in a slightly simplified version. In loadSearch() I dont need to set sortBy to null, but I need to set _filteredSamples=null to retrigger filtering. You have a hanging "}" in loadSearch, but probably just copypaste. Is @ViewScoped from the correct package?

Comment: @JaqenH'ghar I solved the problem, it was nothing wrong with the code at all, it was netbeans. I am using netbeans 7.3 and chose to update it and everything stopped working. I know the code and netbeans are not really related, but I did a complete uninstall and reinstall and everything was working properly again. Thanks for you help though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using netbeans 7.3 and chose to update netbeans. I know normally this should not have any effect on the code whatsoever but it did; everything was working fine up until I updated. I had to do a complete uninstall and reinstall of netbeans. I wouldn't call this a solution, but if anyone else is running 7.3 did a recent update and everything stopped working try to do a complete uninstall and reinstall.